# C++ console keyboard events

Tags: c++, windows, console, keyboard-events

Is there any way to get key events in a Windows console? I need a way to get keydown and keyup events quickly without a GUI. I've tried using getch(), but it doesn't get keyups and waits until a key has been pressed to return.

Comment: You say "without a GUI" but most of the time ( that I know of ) on windows you are using a console inside of a window.  In the cases where you do have a window you can hook that window and capture its messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `GetKeyState` or `GetAsyncKeyState`, but that won't give you keydown/keyup events. It will only tell you what keys are currently down.

So if you really need to get the keydown/keyup events, you could install a hook.
A Console window has a window handle that is owned by code in Windows and a message pump, also owned by code in Windows.

You can get the window handle of of the console window by using [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175(VS.85).aspx)Then install a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook using [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) to listen in on messages send to the console window.

You might try a `WH_MSGFILTER` hook instead.  I don't know if this works for console windows, but it would generate less messages to be ignored if it does work.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`ReadConsoleInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. Watch for events of kind `KEY_EVENT`. This won't work for all keydown events (Ctrl-key, shift-key, Pause-key cannot be read), but most can be read.

Use [`GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to avoid blocking.

Answer (score 2):

I was just curious, how comes such a logical question doesn't have any explanation on Google,
So one has to ask it here. So I googled for: *"keyboard events console application"* and 
guess what ... first 2 links are interesting (but unfortunately, not exactly answers to your question):

- [Processing mouse / keyboard input on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682079%28VS.85%29.aspx).
- [Console event handlers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/console_event_handling.aspx) (like Ctrl-C and window close button).

Comment: I googled the same thing a guess what... the third link pointed to this page.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways. GetKeyboardState would be one of the most obvious.

Answer (score -2):

You can also try [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx)